# How to avoid repeating lambda boilerplate in python?

Tags: python, lambda, boilerplate

I find myself writing too many of these:

```
upper = lambda c   : c.upper()
lower = lambda c   : c.lower()
foo   = lambda a,b : a.foo(b)
```

How can I avoid or at least minimize such boilerplate?

Wasn't (or shouldn't be) there a PEP to allow passing/calling methods as normal procedures?

Comment: Why do you need this? I don't recall ever using such a pattern and I have experience. Maybe there's a better approach.

Comment: I'd not call that boilerplate; the only thing you are 'reusing' is the `lambda` keyword. You could use `operator.methodcaller()` or `functools.partial()`, but you won't save yourself any characters in defining these objects.

Comment: one way is to not use it at all, not sure I get the point of it.

Comment: I am not sure about the PEP you are referring to, but there is PEP8 saying that that column-like alignment you did there is not a good style ;). And indeed, you normally do not need such boilerplate.

Comment: But why do you need all these lambdas in the first place?

Comment: functional programming

Comment: @oyxpiukg Can you elaborate? How is this method more "functional"? In my opinion the `lambda` masks the fact that these are class methods, and makes them look like free functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use unbound methods, rather than creating your own functions.

In your first two examples, you'd probably want `str.upper` and `str.lower`. (If you need to support more than `str`, you could use `operator.methodcaller("upper")` or similar, but be aware that it is almost certainly a bad design decision to deal with both `str` and `bytes` objects with the same code!)

Your third example is more complicated. If you only care about a single type of `a` object, then you'd specify it and it would work just like the `str` examples (e.g. `A.foo`). Similarly, if the value of `b` is constant and known ahead of time, you could use `operator.methodcaller("foo", b)` to get a callable that calls `a.foo(b)` for a given `a` value, but it doesn't help if `b` is also variable.

If you don't know `a`'s type or `b` in advance, you really do need to stick with a function. If you don't like how the lambda expression looks, you can use a regular `def` statement:

```
def foo(a, b):
    return a.foo(b)
```

If it's something you use often, you could write your own variation on `methodcaller` to produce the functions on demand:

```
def my_methodcaller(method_name):
    def inner(obj, *args, **kwargs):
        return getattr(obj, method_name)(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner
```

Then, you'd use `foo = my_methodcaller("foo")`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really see what you're solving. You're just changing your methods from

```
'abc'.upper()
```

to

```
upper('abc')
```

It doesn't really gain you anything, in fact it's a little less readable. If you're using the lambda's to pass into other methods as `key` you can just do something like

```
l = ['ab', 'Aa', 'ca']
sorted(l, key = str.upper)
```

Note that I can just call `str.upper` without having to define a `lambda`

Answer (score 2):

> How can I avoid or at least minimize such boilerplate?

Just do not use it! Or, more specifically:

- Use `c.upper()` instead of `upper(c)`
- Use `c.lower()` instead of `lower(c)`
- Use `a.foo(b)` instead of `foo(a, b)`

Comment: The advantage of the function objects is that you can store them in a mapping and dynamically apply them. There *are* usecases for them.

Comment: I agree, but his examples, especially the `a.foo(b)` one, suggest that his/her goal is to work around using methods in the classical sense, because he/she seems to like the "functional" approach more. If his/her goal is to apply methods in a map-like fashion, then I think we have better advice, such as using list comprehensions.